# What are differences between EFS and BitLocker in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, bitlocker, efs

We learned in MCITP about their features.

Are there any conflicts between EFS and BitLocker?

Can we use both of them together? If so, how?

Comment: Can you explain why you're asking or what specific problem you're facing? I'm by all means no Windows expert but this question seems very vague.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer in this [Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Whats-the-difference-between-BitLocker-Drive-Encryption-and-Encrypting-File-System):

> There are several differences between BitLocker Drive Encryption and
>   the Encrypting File System. BitLocker is designed to help protect all
>   of the personal and systems files on the drive Windows is installed on
>   if your computer is stolen, or if unauthorized users try to access the
>   computer. EFS is used to help protect individual files on any drive on
>   a per-user basis. The table below shows the main differences between
>   BitLocker Drive Encryption and EFS.
>
> #### BitLocker vs. Encrypting File System (EFS)
>
> - BitLocker encrypts all personal and system files on the drive where Windows is installed, or on data drives on the same computer.
> - EFS encrypts individual files on any drive.
> - BitLocker does not depend on the individual user accounts associated with files. BitLocker is either on or off, for all users or groups.
> - EFS encrypts files based on the user account associated with it. If a computer has multiple users or groups, each can encrypt their own
>     files independently.
> - BitLocker uses the Trusted Platform Module (TPM), a special microchip in some newer computers that supports advanced security features.
> - EFS does not require or use any special hardware.
> - You must be an administrator to turn BitLocker encryption on or off once it's enabled.
> - You do not have to be an administrator to use EFS.
> - You can use BitLocker Drive Encryption and the Encrypting File System together to get the protection offered by both features. When
>     using EFS, encryption keys are stored with the computer's operating
>     system. While these are encrypted, that level of security could
>     potentially be compromised if a hacker is able to boot or access the
>     system drive. Using BitLocker to encrypt the system drive can help
>     protect these keys by preventing the system drive from booting or
>     being accessed if it is installed into another computer.